# How to change the name of .exe on runtime

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, c++11

Persay, if I wanna change the .exe on runtime of my program (Like its original name would be: someexe.exe and after you have closed it will change to something random or similiar)

I've seen it happen before and I'm very much interested in implementing it just for fun!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{   
  system("title a.exe");
  std::cout<<"a.exe is the current name of your .exe file\n";
  //do your stuff

  std::cout<<"a.exe is changing to b.exe\n";
  system("RENAME C:\\path\\a.exe b.exe");
  system("title b.exe");
  //do your stuff

  std::cout<<"now b.exe is changing to a.exe\n";
  system("title a.exe");
  system("RENAME C:\\path\\b.exe a.exe");
  //do you stuff
  return 0;
}
```

**But** using `system`command is considered to be [bad](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/) practise therefore you should use [`rename`](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Files/Name.htm) command ,, code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc , char** argv)
{
  rename("a.exe","bii.exe");
  //do your stuff
  rename("bii.exe","a.exe");
  //do your stuff
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure, but the regular [`rename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx) function should work. However, I'm not sure if it's possible to rename a file that is currently held open by the OS (and I have no Windows system that I can test on right now).

If you can't do it on "your own executable", then you'd have to rename the file by running another program [or batchfile] and then resuming your own program [e.g. let the rename program start your program again, and it recognising somehow that it's now the new name and can continue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a copy of the executable file. Then you can rename that file and when you close your current program file you need to transfer control to another program preferably a batch file which deleted the original executable.
in windows system() should be able to do these stuff.
you also need to write your own batch file with code to delete  thr program that calls it.

Comment: So much wrong, it boggles the mind. You do not need to make a copy. You also do not need to transfer control; the system does that for you, if you opted for a proper solution. `system()` is likely the worst idea on Windows. A solid solution implements a launcher, that calls `WaitForSingleObject` on the target application, and performs the `MoveFile` operation once the target application terminates.